# How to show $R/(I+J)\cong (R/I)/(\overline{J})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring and $I, J$ be two ideals. Let $I + J := \{a + b: a \in I, b\in J\}$ be the smallest ideal of $R$ containing $I$ and $J$ and let $\overline{J}$ be the image of $J$ in $R/I$. Show that $$R/(I +J)\cong (R/I)/(\ \overline{J}\ ).$$

Pictorially, 
\begin{align*}
R\xrightarrow []{\pi}  R/I \xrightarrow[]{\phi} R/(I+J)\\
r\mapsto r+I\mapsto r+(I+J)
\end{align*}
$\pi(J)=\overline{J}$. Now I checked that

1. $\phi$ is well-defined.
2. $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism.
3. $\phi$ is surjective.

If I can show that Ker $\phi=(\overline{J})$ then using first isomorphism theorem, I can conclude the result.

Ker$\phi=\{ r+I: r+(I+J)=I+J \}=\{r+I: r\in (I+J)\}$. Now I stuck what to do. I am unable to use that $I+J$ is the smallest ideal containing $I$ and $J$.

Comment: The first inclusion shouldn't be a problem i guess. For the second one: What does it mean for an element $r + I$ to be in the kernel? What does it tell you about any representative $r$? How can you write $r$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\bigl\{r+I\mid r\in I+J\bigr\}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}(I+J)/I$$
since $I\subset I+J$. There remains to apply the 3rd isomorphism theorem.